# Windows 7: Is it possible to attach one window to another?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I'm using the Google Chrome extension "Tabs Outliner" which contains a list of active tabs in a separate window.  I want this window to boot up every time I activate chrome.  Is there a way to pin one window process to another in this way?

Comment: You might want to use that extension in conjunction with a Session Manager extension.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way to do this; you'd need to modify the extension so that it creates or restores its window whenever the Chrome window to which it's attached is created or restored.